# code able to get attachment email and convert to header file when started on any ide but with crontab, only gets attachment and no header filel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

The code properly works when I run it on any python IDE where I can get the png attachment on the email and convert it to header file for thermal printer. But with running it on boot with crontab, I can only get the attachment and not convert it to a header file and it fails the program.

I created a code where it gets the png attachment on an email, convert it to bytes for thermal printer, and print it on thermal printer and it works properly when ran on a python IDE.

qrPrint.py

```
import imaplib
import email
import os
import time
import sys
import importlib
import math
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime

sys.path.append("/home/pi/Python-Thermal-Printer")
from Adafruit_Thermal import *


printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/serial0", 9600, timeout=5)

detach_dir = '/home/pi/Desktop/Codes/' 
imapHost = "imap.gmail.com"
imapUser = "****@gmail.com"
imapPasscode = "****" #app password

def wait_for_network():
    while os.system("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8") != 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    return
wait_for_network()
# connecting to host via SSL
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imapHost)
 
# logging in to servers
imap.login(imapUser, imapPasscode)

while True:
    imap.select("Inbox")
    tmp, data = imap.search(None, "UNSEEN")
    for num in data[0].split():
        tmp, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
        print(f"Subject: {message.get('Subject')}")
        for part in message.walk():
            # multipart are just containers, so we skip them
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue

            # is this part an attachment ?
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            filename = message.get("Subject")
            conv_filename = filename.replace(" ", "-")

            att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, conv_filename + ".png")

            #Check if its already there
            if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
                # finally write the stuff
                fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
                split_text = filename.split(" ")
                title1 = " ".join(split_text[:3]) #qr code #
                title2 = " ".join(split_text[3:len(split_text)]) #name
                print(split_text)
                print(title1)
                print(title2)
                time.sleep(1)
                printer.justify("L")
                printer.println(title1)
                printer.println(title2)
                now = datetime.now()
                printer.println("Date Printed: " + now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
                printer.println("Time Printed: " + now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                # create byte chunks
                a = conv_filename + ".png"
                img = Image.open(detach_dir + a).convert("1", dither = Image.NONE)
                CHUNKS = math.ceil(img.width / 8)
                img_bytes = bytearray()
                for y in range(img.height):
                    for chunk in range(CHUNKS):
                        start = chunk * 8
                        byte = 0
                        for shift, x in enumerate(range(start, start+8)):
                            p = img.getpixel((x, y)) if x < img.width else 1
                            p = int(not p)
                            byte |= p << (7-shift)
                        img_bytes.append(byte)
                #write header file
                header_file = str(conv_filename) +'_bytes.py'
                NAME = str(conv_filename) + '_bytes'
                print("Writing header file", header_file)
                with open(header_file, 'w') as fp:
                    fp.write("width = 150\n".format(NAME))
                    fp.write("height = 150\n\n".format(NAME))
                    fp.write("data = ".format(NAME))
                    fp.write("[\n")
                    row_count = 0
                    for b in img_bytes:
                        fp.write("0x{:02x}, ".format(b))
                        row_count += 1
                        if row_count >= 12:
                            fp.write("\n")
                            row_count = 0
                    fp.write("]\n")
                print("DONE.")
                #print header
                a = str(conv_filename) + "_bytes"  
                qrImage = importlib.import_module(a)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                printer.sleep()      # Tell printer to sleep
                printer.wake()       # Call wake() before printing again, even if reset
                printer.setDefault() # Restore printer to defaults
                printer.justify("C")
                printer.printBitmap(qrImage.width, qrImage.height, qrImage.data)
                printer.println(" ")
                printer.println(" ")
                printer.sleep()      # Tell printer to sleep
                printer.wake()       # Call wake() before printing again, even if reset
                printer.setDefault() # Restore printer to defaults
```

But when running on boot with crontab, it only gets the png attachment. This is the result of running the code on a python IDE. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR3Yr.png)

Crontab code

```
@reboot python3 /runCodes.py &
```

runCodes.py

```
import os

os.system("python3 /home/badz/Desktop/Codes/FOR-IN-NEW.py &")
os.system("python3 /home/badz/Desktop/Codes/qrPrint.py &")
```

The conversion of png to bytes was based on a adafruit thermal printer library on github which included a file like this but i modified it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# This Pythons script uses PIL/Pillow to read in an image file
# and convert it to a header file for use with printBitmap().
#

import math
import argparse
from PIL import Image

# command line parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert image to header file.')
parser.add_argument('input_image', help='the input image file')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out_name', help='output name')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dither', help='dither image')
args = parser.parse_args()

IN_FILE = args.input_image
NAME = args.out_name if args.out_name else IN_FILE.split('.')[0]
DITHER = Image.FLOYDSTEINBERG if args.dither else Image.NONE

# open image file
print("Reading input file", IN_FILE)
img = Image.open(IN_FILE).convert('1', dither=DITHER)

# create byte chunks
print("Converting to bytes.")
CHUNKS = math.ceil(img.width / 8)
img_bytes = bytearray()
for y in range(img.height):
    for chunk in range(CHUNKS):
        start = chunk * 8
        byte = 0
        for shift, x in enumerate(range(start, start+8)):
            p = img.getpixel((x, y)) if x < img.width else 1
            p = int(not p)
            byte |= p << (7-shift)
        img_bytes.append(byte)

# write header file
header_file = NAME+'.py'
print("Writing header file", header_file)
with open(header_file, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("width = 150\n".format(NAME))
    fp.write("height = 150\n\n".format(NAME))
    fp.write("data = ".format(NAME))
    fp.write("[\n")
    row_count = 0
    for b in img_bytes:
        fp.write("0x{:02x}, ".format(b))
        row_count += 1
        if row_count >= 12:
            fp.write("\n")
            row_count = 0
    fp.write("]\n")

print("DONE.")
```

The idea is to create a .py file which is the bytes array of the png file which will be imported to the code but here is the error.

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=19.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.363/19.363/19.363/0.000 ms
Subject: QR Code #45 Vuvu
['QR', 'Code', '#45', 'Vuvu']
QR Code #45
Vuvu
Writing header file QR-Code-#45-Vuvu_bytes.py
DONE.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/badz/Desktop/Codes/TEST123.py", line 109, in <module>
    qrImage = importlib.import_module(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QR-Code-#45-Vuvu_bytes'
```

Comment: What error are you faced with when running the code with crontab? You mention that the code will pass when running through an IDE, but have you tried running the code manually via the CLI (not through crontab) on the system you want to run this on? It is possible that your Python IDE and the system are using different environments/interpreters... perhaps Pillow is not correctly installed on the crontab system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added errors. It does not work running via CLI and does not create another .py file but it works using an IDE and creates a .py file.